# How do I provide domain masking

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, hosting

I run a website `foo.com`. I want to provide domain masking for my clients who run `bar.com`. Specifically, they would like for `xyz.bar.com` to load the content from `foo.com/abc` such that the visitor never leaves the `xyz.bar.com` domain.

This is a standard feature of many web services and it usually involves the `bar.com` people making a DNS entry for `xyz.bar.com` to point at an IP address (e.g. `123.0.0.2`) given to them by `foo.com`.

But how do I set this up at the `foo.com` end?

- Do I have to set up a separate IP address (`123.0.0.xxx`) for each `bar.com` subdomain?
- What is the correct way to set up nginx at my end, so that a given `xyz` gets mapped to the appropriate `abc`?
- Do I need to acquire certificates for `xyz.bar.com` and install them on my end?

Also as a general note, one `xyz` always corresponds to one `abc`, but there are many instances of these pairs. Any advice on how to automate the process is greatly appreciated.

Things that I have looked into and do not want:

- `iframes`, this is work on the clients end, and out of technical scope for most of them.
- URL rewriting et. al., this is a stop gap solution at best and complicates my application code with lost of client and `/abc` special casing.

Comment: This is done with iframes. Though your comment about it being "work on the clients end" doesn't make any sense; it isn't really any work for them, only for you.

Comment: @michael maybe you misunderstand, I would not be serving a webpage with an iframe. My clients would be serving a page from _their_ server (at xyz.bar.com) with an iframe containing my content from foo.com/abc. So the work they would have to do is create that page with the iframe. This is way above the head of someone running a simple wordpress site or similar CMS. Admittedly, there is a tiny amount of work for me in setting the X_Frame_Options header correctly, but the bulk of the work is with the client.

Comment: Err.... so the question text is backward. You actually want your client to provide domain masking for you! In that case, yes, they would have to set up the iframes.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I think the example I gave was pretty simple and clear about who controls which domain and what location the browser should display when content is loaded.


If I use e.g. Zendesk, by default i get foo.zendesk.com, they also offer me the possibility to use support.foo.com. In that case it feels like _they_ provide _me_ with domain masking (especially since they need to install the appropriate SSL certs, set up routing etc.), not the other way around.

Comment: That is not domain masking. Which is probably why everyone is confused. For that, just set up a virtual host in your web server to do whatever you want, and have the DNS records changed to point to your server.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell me then what it is usually called. Naming things is a notoriously hard problem in CS.

Comment: That's so common that there's no _special_ name for it. Virtually every web site is set up this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to set up a separate IP address (123.0.0.xxx) for each bar.com subdomain?

No. One IP address can host multiple domains, this is implemented using virtual hosts in your web server software.

> What is the correct way to set up nginx at my end, so that a given xyz gets mapped to the appropriate abc?

You set up a virtual host for `xyz` by using `server_name xyz;` directive in your nginx configuration.

Then you use `root` directive to specify the desired root directory for that domain on your server.

You can also configure nginx to use application server for that domain.

> Do I need to acquire certificates for xyz.bar.com and install them on my end?

Yes, you need to have valid certificates for all virtual hosts matching their domain names that use TLS on your server.